Proof that the set of all doubly stochastic matrices is a manifold?
I'm trying to find the proof of a fact that the set of all doubly stochastic matrices of positive elements:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}\mathcal{P}_{n} := \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}; ~ \forall i,j \in \{ 1,\cdots,n \}\times \{ 1,\cdots,n \} ~~ X_{ij}>0, X1_n = 1_n, X^{\top}1_n = 1_n \},
\end{equation}
is actually a manifold, but so far couldn't. Here, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we denote $1_n = [1,\cdots,1]^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I guess one can make use of the preimage theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem) to show this. Could anyone help?

It's an open subset of an affine subspace...

@SassatelliGiulio You cleared things up!! Thank you very much.
